# How to see where rviz is looking for plugins

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a package that add a simple plugins to rviz, following the rviz_plugin_tutorial example.
It now compiles with catkin_make.
I have the export tag in package.xml and a plugin_description.xml.
I have properly source my catkin_workspace.

But if I run rviz, it does not appear in the add panel list. and I have no debug/error anywhere

I am now looking for some ways to debug this. Is there a way to see where 'pluginlib' is looking for plugins, or other way to have a bit more verbosity on the plugin part ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265518/how-to-see-where-rviz-is-looking-for-plugins/) by [Bobox](https://answers.ros.org/users/27011/bobox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [wiki/pluginlib - Providing a Plugin - Querying ROS Package System For Available Plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.Querying_ROS_Package_System_For_Available_Plugins).

That is basically what RViz does.

Check #q163476 for a related question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bobox](https://answers.ros.org/users/27011/bobox/) on 2017-07-05**:
Thanks the related question has all the answers I need, shame I did not find it in my research before asking my own.